# Java AudioClip not working

Tags: java, audio, applet

My wav sound won't play even though my code is based on a working exemple. I don't know where lied my errors. I found this code exemple on the internet:

```
import javax.swing.*;  
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;  
import java.applet.*;  
import java.io.*;  
class Testing extends JFrame implements ActionListener  
{  
  JButton btn = new JButton("Play Sound");  
  File wavFile = new File("c:\\Windows\\media\\ding.wav");  
  AudioClip sound;  
  public Testing()  
  {  
    setSize(300,100);  
    setLocation(400,300);  
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
    JPanel jp = new JPanel();  
    btn.addActionListener(this);  
    jp.add(btn);  
    getContentPane().add(jp);  
    pack();  
    try{sound = Applet.newAudioClip(wavFile.toURL());}  
    catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}  
  }  
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){sound.play();}  
  public static void main(String args[]){new Testing().setVisible(true);}      
}
```

It works fine. I created a WavReader class which will load an AudioClip sound. My Button has a WavReader attribute. What I am trying to do is making the WavReader sound play through my Button's MouseEnetered event. Here is my WavReader class:

```
import javax.swing.*;  
import java.awt.*;  
import java.awt.event.*;  
import java.applet.*;  
import java.io.*;  

public class WavReader {  

  File wavFile; 
  public AudioClip sound;  

  public WavReader(String file) {  

    wavFile = new File(file);

    try {
      sound = Applet.newAudioClip(wavFile.toURL());
    }  
    catch(Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }  


  public void playSound() {
  sound.play();

  }

  public void stopSound() {
     sound.stop();
  }

}
```

And here are chunks of my personalized button:

```
public class ButtonMenu extends JButton{

  public ButtonMenu() {

    private WavReader reader = new WavReader("blabla.wav");

   addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
 public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
   setForeground(Color.red);
   reader.playSound();
 }

      public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {     
       setForeground(Color.white);
          reader.stopSound();
        }
      }   // end MouseAdaptater
  );  // end MouseListener
 }

}
```

There is no errors at runtime, however my sound wont play. Can you tell me what  am doing wrong ?

The only difference I can see is that my AudioClip attribute here is not part of any JFrame but of my WavReader class which is part of my Button's.

Comment: Try it using a Java Sound based `Clip` as seen in the [info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/javasound/info).

Comment: Thanks but why does my above code fail at playing the blabla.wav sound?

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure by the looks of the code but did you import the correct library to play the audio?

Comment: Yes everything is correctly imported, I don;t get any error at compilation.

Comment: I also made sure it gets in my WavReader playSound() method.
The only difference I can see is that my AudioClip attribute here is not part of any JFrame but of my WavReader class which is part of my Button's. If it is the reason I don't know why.